# What is the storyboard equivalent to an M file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

So I have been using objective C and XIB files to do iOS programming for a while. I am starting now to learn storyboards and I am having a hard time figuring out how to write code for the storyboard. For example I am making a view where a user inputs info. Using my old style I would make a m, h, and a xib file. Edit the xib, link the elements to their definitions in the H file and make an iboutlet so that I can use it in the M file.

Now I have made a storyboard and added elements, how can I actually reference the elements in code, and where do I even put the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a subclass of the UIViewController, UIView, etc... Jus exactly as you would have done with a XIB. Then you set the class in the desired object in the storyboard just as you would have done with a xib...

[image: Add Class to storyboard UIViewController]

Once the class is set you can link selectors etc as you would have done with a XIB file.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I have made a storyboard and added elements, how can I actually reference the elements in code, and where do I even put the code?

It's exactly the same as with .xib files. You can think of a single storyboard file as a collection of .xib files. A single .xib file typically contained a view controller of some kind and a view graph; when you instantiated the view controller, the view controller and its view graph were read out of the .xib and turned into objects. It's largely the same with storyboards -- you still have .m and .h files for your view controller class, and you still use IBOutlets to connect elements in the storyboard to properties or instance variables in your view controller.

The main thing that's different is that a storyboard allows you to specify the transitions between view controllers, so that you no longer have to write the code that creates a new view controller and transitions to it.